# How to Copy Data into an Array/Manipulate It/Paste to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

**SETUP**
I have an Excel file with my source data in Columns in A to J.
In Column K there's a 'Send Type' value which can either be "Many" or "Single".
In Column L there's a 'Send Count' value, which is numeric ("N").

**OBJECTIVE**

1. copy the source data
2. insert N-1 rows
3. paste that data N-1 times into those rows.

I'd like the result to be the data pasted N times.

- If N is 1, there's no copy/insert/paste required
- if N is greater than 1, the result should be the data displayed N times.

Example Excel Sheet
[image]

**CURRENT VBA**

```vb
Sub Copy_PROD_Paste_Send_Count()

    Dim Copy_Row        As Integer
    Dim Send_Count      As Variant
    Dim TargetMapCount  As Integer
    Dim ProgressCount   As Integer
    Dim Send_Type       As String
    Dim ProgressTarget  As Integer
   
    Copy_Row = 1
    TargetMapCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("K:K"), "Many", Range("L:L"))
    Send_Type = Cells(Copy_Row, "K")
    ProgressTarget = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A")) + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("K:K"), "Many", Range("L:L")) - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K:K"), "Many")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Do While (Cells(Copy_Row, "A") <> "")
        Send_Count = Cells(Copy_Row, "L")
        Send_Type = Cells(Copy_Row, "K")

        If (Send_Type = "Many" And (Send_Count > 1) And IsNumeric(Send_Count)) Then
            
            Range(Cells(Copy_Row, "A"), Cells(Copy_Row, "L")).Copy
            Range(Cells(Copy_Row + 1, "A"), Cells(Copy_Row + Send_Count - 1, "L")).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Copy_Row = Copy_Row + Send_Count - 1
                    
            ProgressCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                         
            Application.StatusBar = "Updating :" & ProgressCount - 1 & " of " & ProgressTarget & ": " & Format((ProgressCount - 1) / ProgressTarget, "0%")
                
        End If
        Copy_Row = Copy_Row + 1
          
    Loop        

End Sub
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

The macro executes up to about 2-3k rows before crashing. I need to run up to 15k.

I understand I should try to copy the data into an array, manipulate it within that array and then paste the results back to a new sheet. I can't work out how.

Comment: Copy the 'source' range into an array. Build the 'output' table into another array (10, sum(N))  and then write that array in one line back to the sheet. Should be incredibly quick.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I'm unclear on how to do that (my VBA skills are non-existent and I basically scrape the web to assemble things). I'll try to research how to do those things but in the meantime any pointers or, even better, example VBA would be gratefully welcomed

Comment: I've had a go at writing it based on my comments.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really do appreciate both your initial guidance regarding using arrays instead of ranges, and then taking the time to do that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a routine that copies the input table to an array and then builds an output array (in memory) from the inputs, before dumping the output array back to the worksheet.

Note: It ignores the Single/Many column and instead just uses the value in the last column to determine how many times to repeat the output.

```
Sub RepeatData()

    'Declarations
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        'Find Last Row of table
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        'Find Last Column of table
        LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        'Copy table to array
        Dim ArrInput
        ArrInput = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value
        
        'sum up multiples (total of last column in table) so we know how big the output array needs to be
        OutputRows = 1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2, LastColumn).Resize(UBound(ArrInput) - 1, 1))
        
        'Create output array for filling
        ReDim ArrOutput(1 To OutputRows, 1 To LastColumn)
        
        'Copy data across
        o = 1   ' start outputting to index 1 of ArrOutput
        
        For r = 1 To LastRow
            
            If r = 1 Then                   ' if on header row
                m = 1                       ' set repeat to once (set m to 1)
            Else                            ' if not on header row
                m = ArrInput(r, LastColumn) ' set repeat to value in last column
            End If
            
            For n = 1 To m                  ' loop to repeat
                For c = 1 To LastColumn     ' cycle across columns
                    ArrOutput(o, c) = ArrInput(r, c)    'copy value
                Next
                o = o + 1                   ' increment output index
            Next
        Next

    End With
    
    'Write output array to sheet, 5 rows below the end of the input table
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 5, 1).Resize(UBound(ArrOutput), UBound(ArrOutput, 2)).Value = ArrOutput

End Sub
```